# Restrict access for a RedHat user to one directory

Tags: ssh, rhel, ftp, chroot, sftp

I am using RedHat Gnu/Linux I have a group of 10 users, and I'd like to restrict the access to all of them. Here are the rules I'd like to respect for them:

1. For each user `user_i`, there is a folder named `user_i`. The `user_i` should have writing and reading permissions on his directory and all the files/directories in it.
2. When the `user_i` connects to the machine, he should find himself in the `user_i` directory by default.
3. He (user `user_i`) can't see the other directories or files and has no access to them. The `user_i` directory is his "root" directory.

I created the group, I created all users and assigned them to this one group, and I created all folders. But I don't know how to continue beyond this.

I looked online and on this website. Most results found talk about modifying `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for users connecting with SSH, while mine also needs to connect via FTP and SFTP. And other guides talk about giving access to all users of a certain group to one shared folder, which isn't my case because I need a **separate** folder to every user.

**Edit:**

Thanks everyone for your interaction and the useful information and I apologize about the confusion. Here I'll clarify the specification:

4. The `user_i` folders are new folders created in /transfers directory specifically for every user and named after its username. So the hierarchy looks similar to this:

   ```
   /  
   --transfers/ 
   ----user_i/ 
   ------received_data/
   ------archive_data/
   ```

   Every `user_i` will write and read data in the subfolders `received_data` and `archive_data`. He can't access any other directory, including the typical Linux directories and specifically the directories of other users (the other 9 `user_i`).

   By connecting to the server, he should get to `user_i` folder by default, and therefore only see the two subfolders `received_data` and `archive_data`.
5. All `user_i` belong to a group created specifically for them.

Comment: When you create a new user, it should give them a home directory, therefore this is done for you. You then need to set permission on the directories, see `man chmod`. I see nothing in your spec that groups these users.

Comment: Sounds almost like each user should have their own container, or chroot.

Comment: When you say "can't see the other directories or files and has no access to them", what do you mean by "other"? Do you just want the users isolated from each others' home directories, or do you want the users not to have access to /bin and /tmp ?

Comment: @richard: Yeah, home directories are created by default. But the directories we're using here are different as you can see in my Edit above.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I think so. My manager asks me to chroot the folders with chroot command, but he doesn't know more. I'm still looking online and trying to figure it out.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: The user has access to just one directory (and everything inside it). Please check my Edit above and you'll find how the filesystem hierarchy looks like.

Comment: OK. If the users have ssh access, presumably they'll need a shell and commands such as `ls`, `cat`, `cp`, `mv`, and `rm`. Where can those commands go?

Comment: I confirm that they'll need to execute shell commands. I'm trying to figure out how to do it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The requirement that each user cannot access any directory other than `received_data` and `archive_data` makes it a little messy. But you can likely install `busybox-static`, which will give you a shell and other useful commands that don't need shared libraries. Then, for each restricted user, copy the busybox executable into one of the two allowed subdirectories, symlink `sh` to it, set the user's shell in whatever password database you're using to be the pathname (post-chroot) to this shell, and admonish the users not to delete `sh` or `busybox`.

Answer (score 2):

You are most probably looking for the `ChrootDirectory` option for `sshd_config`.

> For each user user_i, there is a folder named user_i. The user_i should have writing and reading permissions on his directory and all the files/directories in it.

This is not possible with `chroot`. The users can not have write access to the directory they are `chroot`-ed in, because it would be security vulnerability (CVE-2009-2904). Every user needs its own directory inside the `chroot` he can write in. The filesystem hierarchy can look like this:

```
directory -- owner:group permissions
/chroots/ -- root:root 700
  user_i/ -- root:root 700
    data/ -- user_i:chroot_users 700
```

The `sshd_config` can look like this:

```
Match Group chroot_users
  ChrootDirectory /chroots/%u/
```

This will separate the users. But note that these users do not have any programs to run in their separated directories! You can give them only SFTP access:

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
```

or copy the required programs into every chroot, for example for simple `bash`:

```
cp --parents /bin/bash /chroots/user_i/
cp --parents `ldd /bin/bash | cut -d'>' -f2 | awk '{print $1}'` /chroots/user_i/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand this right, I only have to modify the sshd_config file and include the 3 lines and that's it?  
Am I going to need to chmod the permissions of folders? What permissions should I give in this case?  
My manager asks me to use the chroot command, is it really necessary?

Comment: The permissions are in the answer. The `sshd` will use the `chroot` "command" for you if you specify `ChrootDirectory` option in `sshd_config`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I modified the permissions without a problem. But when I modified the sshd_config file, the server became unreachable. All SSH, FTP and SFTP connections were blocked. Is this normal? Is there a method to do this with the basic chroot command without modifying the sshd_config file?

Comment: No. It is not normal. Check for the errors produced by the sshd